# Unable to send cloudwatch logs to loggly using a blueprint lambda - Invalid ciphertext

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I am trying to use the loggly Lambda blueprint to send cloudwatch logs to loggly. I am doing this because I have a bunch of lambdas that I need to have a single point of viewing logs. I've followed [this guide](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/loggly/Content/admin/cloudwatch-logs.htm?cshid=loggly_cloudwatch-logs) and have run into an issue when I check the lambda logs after a test

Command used to do ciphertext

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id alias/logglyCustomerToken --plaintext "<my token>"
```

KMS key was created using symetric and default settings, can't delete key to try again or at least I don't know how to delete it and thinking I shouldn't change the code to match a new one

Lambda log message when failed test

```
INFO    InvalidCiphertextException: null
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidCiphertextException',
  time: 2020-07-08T02:48:55.536Z,
  requestId: 'cf0df165-5a59-4db0-beef-5d1ae3619c37',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 79.27899980360486
}
```

Comment: Also ask this question at [THWACK — The SolarWinds IT Community](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/t5/Loggly-Discussions/bd-p/loggly-discussions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to fix `InvalidCiphertextException`:

1. Open the Lambda function in AWS console.
2. Scroll down to the `Environment Variables` section & click `Edit`:

[image]

3. Delete the value of `kmsEncryptedCustomerToken` & replace it with the customer token you got from `https://<your-company>.loggly.com/tokens`. The token looks like this: `72cf6d64-256e-449d-aabd-49e1f422ed58`.
4. Expand the `Encryption Configuration` section at the bottom.
5. Select `Enable helpers for encryption in transit`.
6. Click the `Encrypt` button that appears next to `kmsEncryptedCustomerToken`.

[image]

7. Select the `logglyCustomerToken` KMS key (CMK) & `Encrypt`.
8. Finally, `Save` the environment variables.

The Lambda function test should succeed now. If you face any other issues or need a complete end-to-end screenshot-guided tutorial for the entire process of sending CloudWatch Logs to Loggly, please see [my blog post](https://harishkm.in/2020/07/16/send-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-to-solarwinds-loggly-using-an-aws-lambda-function/).

Comment: Thank you this worked, sorry for slow reply forgot to reply and mark accepted answer. :D